# Correct usage of "infringement of copyright"

Tags: meaning, expressions

Does the term *infringement of copyright* apply in the following situations?

- I am attending a training session
  conducted by a third-party training
  company. I want to audio record the
  sessions. Will this come under infringement of copyright?

I would like to raise an another question.

- Say I am attending a meeting in my
  company. What if I want to record
  those meetings in my mobile phone
  for later writing notes?
  Is this subject to infringement of copyright?

I have gone through Wikipedia to find the definition. But these are some situations where I cannot find any real-time references.

Comment: Off topic? chr chr

Comment: A site has been proposed in Area 51 : http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3346/intellectual-property-law

Comment: "Infringement of copyright" is grammatically correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would say something like

> This presentation is copyrighted.

or

> This presentation is subject to copyright

And you might also say

> Would recording this presentation be considered copyright infringement?

or

> Would recording this presentation infringe your copyright?

As for the example questions you posted, the first one sounds odd to me but I'd say it's probably acceptable and the listener will understand, but I'd say this instead:

> I am attending a training session conducted by a third party training company. I want to audio record the sessions. Would this be considered copyright infringment?

For your second example there is a bit of ambiguity about your `this` pronoun in the second sentence.

> Say I am attending a meeting in my company, what if I want to record those meetings in my mobile phone for later writing notes. Is this subject to infringment of copyright?

I understand the meaning but what the question is really asking (at face value) is "Will my recording have its copyright infrigned?" which probably isn't what you want; the copyright you are concerned about is the meeting's copyright.  So I'd say

> Say I am attending a meeting in my company. What if I want to record those meetings in my mobile phone for later writing notes? Would this infringe the company's copyright?

Answer (score 0):

I would more likely say:

> ... Will this be copyright infringement / infringement of copyright?

Or

> Is this considered a form of copyright infringement?

Or

> Is this subject to/Does this come under copyright laws?

Comment: Your last example should probably be "Is this subject to"/"Does this come under"